# Listing files in a specific folder

Tags: swift, macos, file

I've created a folder called "Photos" in the Documents folder.

Using Swift code, I want to print the names of the files in the Photos folder.

Comment: The location of the folder `Documents` depends on whether the app is sandboxed or not, the class to get file names is `NSFileManager`

Comment: @vadian I've read some about NSFileManager but haven't yet found answer to this concrete example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do {
    let files = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/Users/username/Documents/Photos")
    print(files)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4**

```
do {
    let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: "/Users/username/Documents/Photos")

    print(files)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```